# Numeric values of camera angles while tracking

Tags: camera

When tracking, for example the origin, and moving the camera in
space, the camera angles are clearly not zero. Still, in the 
parameter display the 'Transform/Rotation' is displayed as (0,0,0).
How is this possible?

[image]

How can I get the real camera angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Track to` constraint on the camera (it's what I see), or a parent relation maybe. 
The Rotation in the properties panel does not take in account the constraints or parenting effects, so it shows 0.

You can enter `bpy.context.scene.camera.matrix_world.to_euler()` in the console and it should give you the real orientation of the camera.